# Erro em condição IF

Tags: php, html, sql

Estou a fazer um programa em PHP mas estou a ter um problema. Quero que, quando o $user_info seja igual a Tiago Goncalves, mostre a imagem do utilizador. A verdade é que é mostrado no website todas as 3 imagens.

HTML

Comment: Colega, não é uma boa prática aqui na comunidade você descaracterizar sua pergunta. Pense que ela pode ser útil para outros colegas no futuro. Sobre sua [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/207199) na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/319612/45810) do colega, acredito que não será aceita. Sua própria pergunta já diz: "*- quando o $user_info seja igual a Tiago Goncalves.*". Se não quer seu nome exibido aqui, busque orientação dos [moderadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note que não está utilizando o comparador e sim atribuindo o valor à variável:

```
if( $user_info['nome'] = 'Tiago Gonçalves')
```

O correto seria:

```
if( $user_info['nome'] == 'Tiago Gonçalves')
```

Corrigindo o código:

```
if( $user_info['nome'] == 'Tiago Gonçalves'){
   echo "<img src='img/users/Tiago.jpg'>";
}
else if( $user_info['nome'] == 'Alexandre Salgado'){
   echo "<img src='img/users/Alexandre.jpg'>";
}
else if( $user_info['nome'] == 'Ricardo Cardoso'){
   echo "<img src='img/users/Ricardo.jpg'>";
}
```

Comment: Realmente Pedro... se a gente vem de outras linguagens para o PHP/JavaScript que usam dois "=" na comparação, às vezes a gente se confunde! Percebi logo de início que era isso!

Comment: Recentemente li esse debate no Meta. Recomendo a leitura, é de grande "ajuda" https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4329/como-ser-um-usu%c3%a1rio-mais-dedicado-no-stack-overflow?cb=1 e se aplica para fora do SOPT

Comment: As imagens são realmente diferentes ? O conteúdo do `$user_info` muda ?

Comment: São 100% diferentes.

Comment: Estranho que o código que editei acima está funcionando perfeitamente aqui. Verifique se o valor que você está comparando bate com o valor que vem na variável. Os testes manuais que fiz aqui funcionaram 100%

Comment: Utilizou a minha base de dados?

Comment: Ja resolvi. Utilizei user_info mas em vez de $user_info['nome'], utilizei $user_info['id'] == '1'

Comment: @TiagoGonçalves marque a resposta como certa. Visto que o Pedro conseguiu resolver o seu problema. É importante para SOpt e para ele que merece ser recompensado após analisar o código, testar e publicar a resposta correta. Veja mais aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079